# Checkbox persist state while traversing over array with ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I an using ng-inculde to display an object with check box my issue is if I change the object with in the same page .. check box still persist its state .

For example :

I have model like

```
 $scope.templates = [{
    name: 'Object 1',
    url: 'template1.html',
    options:['A1','B2']},
{
    name: 'Object 2',
    url: 'template1.html',
    options:['A1','B2']}];
```

when selected object is object 1 and I check "A1" after that I chnage the selection and move to Object 2 it still shows A1 as selected.

[Detailed scenario is given in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shukla2009/98RjR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that this wasn't working because the JSFiddle you have above uses the same value for the `options` array values:

```
$scope.templates = [{
    name: 'Object 1',
    url: 'template1.html',
    options:['A1','B2']}
{
    name: 'Object 2',
    url: 'template1.html',
    options:['A1','B2']
}];
```

When AngularJS is doing its dirty checking to decide if the value needs to be updated in the DOM, it will need to compare/check the inner values. In your case, the values are the *same* for the `options` array and as a result AngularJS decides that no update is needed to the document.

I made some minor changes to your JSFiddle to:

1. Use `ng-model` for the checkbox "persistence"
2. Modified the `options` array on `Object 2` to be unique to the first object
3. Upgraded AngularJS library to 1.2.1 *(this will not be needed for your solution)*

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterXen/3gcqE/2/**